# Strategy for application web + offline

Tags: workbox

I am unable to configure the correct strategy in Workbox for the following context.
I want that :

- the maximum file can be cached locally to speed up loading.
- but if a newer version is available online for the file, it must be updated locally (espacialy with js files)
- the application must work in offline mode but it must always use the latest version of the file.

It may be simple but I can't do it with pre-caching only (my changes don't go down to client's browser).Pre-caching is working for off-line mode (if I have all the files...) but the files are not updated (I must do it manually...).
If you have an idea (and exemple...) thank's a lot !
guen

Answer (score 1):

`workbox-precaching` should handle most of what you describe. The one thing that you need to be aware of is that the service worker lifecycle controls when the user ends up seeing the updated versions of precached resources.

There's more info [about the lifecycle in this article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle), and there is [some guidance in the Workbox documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#offer_a_page_reload_for_users) about how you can detect when there's an update to precaached resources post-load, and show a prompt asking users to refresh to get the latest versions of everything.

If you're running into a scenario in which that guidance doesn't help, then [filing a bug](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues) with reproduction steps in the Workbox GitHub repo is a good next step.